# Something wrong with my wine installation that gives me this red mark

Tags: wine

What is the error behind this red mark and how to fix it?

[image: error message]

The error message follows:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
>
> The error message was: ' Unknown Error: '<class 'KeyError'>' ("The cache has no package named 'wine-devel-i386'")'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies

Comment: Try  This `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: @Rahul it asked me about the installation path of matlab, i dont have matlab so i pressed cancel and it ends without download or install anything

Comment: Matlab??  are you installing matlab??

Comment: @Rahul No, but many programs asks me about the installation path of matlab and i dont know the reason